# Variogram Software

Tags: saga, software-recommendations

I would like to know wich software are suitable to create Variograms and to know sill, nugget and range easily.

I would prefer if this software could run in Linux.

I've tried SAGA but lacks a lot of documentation, if you know some other software would be aprecciate.

Comment: There are a lot of softwares and documentation at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/software-for-making-semi-variograms-and-analyses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/), it uses [R](https://www.r-project.org/), SAGA and Google Earth or [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping of Environmental Variables](https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ESDB_Archive/eusoils_docs/Images/EUR22904EN.pdf) with R and Saga:

With [R](https://www.r-project.org/), you can do what you want:

- R only : [Geostatistics packages on CRAN](https://web.archive.org/web/20120404190232/http://geodacenter.asu.edu:80/projects/rsp/content/geostatistics-p), [A minimal Introduction to geostatictics with R/gstats](http://www.itc.nl/%7Erossiter/teach/R/gs_short_ex.pdf), [Analyzing Spatial Data with R: Worked example: geostatistics](http://www.bias-project.org.uk/ASDARcourse/unit4_slides.pdf) , [Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSAGA/index.html), and and many more...
- R with SAGA GIS, [RSAGA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSAGA/index.html)
- R with GRASS GIS  [Short Introduction to Geostatistical and Spatial Data Analysis
  with GRASS and R statistical data language](http://grass.fbk.eu/statsgrass/grass_geostats.html) or [Ordinary Kriging Example: GRASS-R Bindings](https://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/software/r-advanced-statistical-package/working-spatial-data/ordinary-kriging-example-grass-r-bindings/)
- R with QGIS
- ...